# VB.NET Application - Open website vs project file acts differently

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I noticed one weird thing today, and I'll appreciate your input on this.

I was assigned to work on a VB.NET project. I took the project files from the server locally.

I opened Visual Studio and then did open project, the project loaded in the solution and I did build, I got errors, pls check screenshot:

http://gyazo.com/3fe2ea4d5ff8fd073355d43160861e70.png?1348166929

2nd try, I opened Visual Studio and instead open project, I did open website, I selected the folder where the files are located and then open website. I build the solution, it says build succeded and the website runs fine in the browser.

Now I want to know why that's happening, why when I am trying to open as a project I am getting errors, and when I am opening as a website, website starts ok.

Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS, Projects and Websites are different - a Project is a collection of files managed by a *.proj file (e.g. *.csproj, *.vcproj, *.vbproj), whereas a Website is just a filesystem folder without much in the way of project management metadata.

The second main difference is that Websites have a different Build process - unless you explicitly opt-in to pre-compilation the project is not compiled at design-time, instead everything is compiled by the webserver at runtime, which means you need to distribute all of your source code.

It also means that compile-time errors are harder to detect. You will get the same errors in a Website as in a Project, it just means you need to perform a live website action that uses the same error-prone *.vb files, and you'll get a lovely YSoD error then (rather than in the IDE before you publish it).

"Websites" were introduced in VS2005 as an "easier" alternative to VS2003's ASP.NET Web Applications, but there was a lot of backlash from developers - I wouldn't be surprised if they removed it from a future VS release.